# How do i make my article two-column? IEEEtran document class

Tags: two-column, ieeetran

```
\documentclass[12pt, onecolumn, draftcls]{IEEEtran}


\title{Energy harvesting from wireless signals a review}
\author{}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    With a projection of 40 billion IoT devices \cite{zikria2021next} to be installed by 2025 there is an increasingly higher demand for reliable sources of power. As battery replacement and maintenance at such a large scale becomes harder and less reliable, a continuous source of power is in demand.  One suggested solution is harvesting energy from wireless via electromagnetic waves. The main contender for such a system is the rising 5G network.
\end{abstract}

\section{introduction}

5G is the fifth generation of cellular network. Cellular networks communicate using “cells”. Each cell has a certain range and maximum capacity that it can connect to. A problem is that cells next to each other with the same frequencies end up having trouble with signals being mixed. This is fixed by having each cell having a different frequency. This causes another issue however, which is that the number of slices of frequencies is finite. This is solved by finding the reuse distance (minimum distance required for frequencies to not affect each other) and reusing the frequency. This is called a frequency reuse pattern.

The most common shape used for cell towers are hexagons

Up to now, cell signals have generally been between 500-2500MHz. 

5G will use two different channels. FR1 which is 400-6000MHz and FR2 which is 24-50GHz(mm wave)

Lower frequencies are easier to transmit, goes through objects (like bass of a song through walls) however bandwidth and speed is much slower 

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{citations}

\end{document}
```

So this is my code. Im super new to latex, im a freshman in uni who has to write a literature review. I have to write it in ieeetran style, but i cannot figure out how to make it double-columned (or make abstract bold)

Comment: Have you tried to change the class option from ``onecolumn`` to ``twocolumn``?

Comment: ... or simply just remove `onecolumn`

Comment: Also, removing `draftcls` gives a much better looking document

Answer (score 2):

As @SayOL and @lhf have already pointed out in comments, you should (a) get rid of the `onecolumn` option (or replace it with `twocolumn`) in order to get a two-column layout and (b) get rid of the `draftcls` option to generate an abstract with **bold lettering**.

In addition, you should get into the habit of leaving one or more blank lines between paragraphs of text. In fact, whitespace is often your friend; don't be afraid to use it. And, if your document needs to typeset a lot of scientific units, be sure to load the [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package and use its `\qty` and `\qtyrange` macros to typeset quantitities and their associated units in a way that is guaranteed to meet common typographic standards. For instance, it's common usage to insert a "thinspace" between a quantity and its associated unit; you'll get this automatically if you use the `\qty` macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional (Times Roman text and math fonts)
\usepackage{siunitx} % for \qty and \qtyrange macros

\title{Energy harvesting from wireless signals: A review}

\author{Seyed Sohrab Farjami}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

With a projection of 40 billion IoT devices \cite{zikria2021next} to be installed by 2025 there is an increasingly higher demand for reliable sources of power. As battery replacement and maintenance at such a large scale becomes harder and less reliable, a continuous source of power is in demand.  One suggested solution is harvesting energy from wireless via electromagnetic waves. The main contender for such a system is the rising 5G network.

\end{abstract}


\section{Introduction}

5G is the fifth generation of cellular network. Cellular networks communicate using “cells.” Each cell has a certain range and maximum capacity that it can connect to. A problem is that cells next to each other with the same frequencies end up having trouble with signals being mixed. This is fixed by having each cell having a different frequency. This causes another issue however, which is that the number of slices of frequencies is finite. This is solved by finding the re-use distance (minimum distance required for frequencies to not affect each other) and re-using the frequency. This is called a frequency re-use pattern.

The most common shape used for cell towers is the hexagon.

Up to now, cell signals have generally been between 
\qty{500}{\mega\hertz} and \qty{2.5}{\giga\hertz}. 

5G will use two different channels: FR1, which is between
\qty{400}{\mega\hertz} and 
\qty{6}{\giga\hertz}, and FR2, which is from 
\qtyrange{24}{50}{\giga\hertz} (mm wave).

Lower frequencies are easier to transmit and go through objects (like bass of a song through walls), but bandwidth and speed are much lower.

%\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
%\bibliography{citations}

\end{document}
```